# Fill the fields of a form automatically after a field is filled using springs and jsp

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a form that lets the user to either add an employee's details or edit existing details. Once the user enters the employee id in the form and presses search button, then the controller will search for the details of the employee and fill the form. Can this be done without resending the page to the user? I'm using jsp and springs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use ajax, jquery to populate the forms without resending the page